# The import android.app.usage cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-activity

I tried to import this package - `android.app.usage` - for getting application usage but was not able to get it.

While importing this package, I am not able to access relevant classes and getting only error such as *".... cannot be resolved"*.

Comment: Set target to Android 5.0 (API Level: 21)

Answer (score 0):

You need API Level 21 to access this package.

Comment: @Dineshdhinnu, Is it useful ?